# Can we have a single sign on for multiple gcloud projects at one shot using a gmail account?

Tags: gcloud

I have 3-5 gcloud projects. I develop an application which has sso on one project, but I need to use some HTTP APIs on the other projects using the same account.But I do not want to do Sign in to those projects again. So, is there a way to do Single sign on to multiple projects using user accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You provide little detail but you should consider [Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/)

IAP implements a constituent of Google's [BeyondCorp](https://cloud.google.com/beyondcorp/) strategy which inherently focus on securing micro-services instead of attempting the define an impermeable network perimeter.

It leverages Google Identity (e.g. Google|Gmail accounts) and IAM to permit the definition of organization-wide security policies.